# How to implement a KeyListener to an object in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm attempting to make Frogger in java for a school project but I'm having a lot of difficulties setting up KeyListener for the actual frog character.

I've tried setting up key bindings, requesting focus for the JPanel and JFrame, moving around where the character is initiated but nothing has seemed to work. This is the remnants of my attempts.

This is the program that runs my game.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frogger
{
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frogger");
 CPT c = new CPT();
 public Frogger()
 {
  frame.setBounds(0,0,700,500);
  frame.setResizable(false);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.add(c);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
   new Frogger();
 }

}
```

The main game

```java
public CPT() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    label = new JLabel("Frogger");
    frame1 = new JFrame("Main");
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,50));
    label.setBounds(275,10,250,250);
    button1 = new JButton("PLAY");
    button1.setBounds(300,350,100,50);
    button1.setOpaque(false);
    button1.setVisible(true);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.add(label);


    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(700,500);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        frame1.setFocusable(false);
        button1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.add(new TrainCanvas());
        frame1.add(p1);
        p1.requestFocus();
      } 
    });
    this.add(button1); }
```

This is the TrainCanvas class that Draws the cars in the games as well as the frog

```java
  class TrainCanvas extends JComponent
 {
    private int lastX = 0;
    private int lastX_1 = 0;
    private int lastX_2 = 0;


    public TrainCanvas() {
      Thread animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            repaint();
            try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (Exception ex) {}
          }
        }
      });

      animationThread.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

      //Draws Train 1
      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();

      int trainW_1 = 100;
      int trainH_1 = 5;
      int trainSpeed_1 = 3;

      int x = lastX + trainSpeed_1;

      if (x > w + trainW_1) {
        x = -trainW_1;
      }

      gg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      gg.fillRect(x, h/2 + trainH_1, trainW_1, trainH_1);
      lastX = x;
      Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
      frog = new Rectangle(f_x,f_y,25,25);
      g3.fill(frog);
      g3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   }
}
```

Finally, the Key Listener

```java
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
      if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      {
        CPT.f_y -= 100;
        repaint();
      }
      else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
      {
        CPT.f_x += 100;
        repaint();
      }
      else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
      {
        CPT.f_x -= 100;
        repaint();
      }
      else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
        CPT.f_y += 100;
        repaint();
      }
      else {}
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {} 
}
```

The program runs perfectly fine without giving me any errors, which is making this troublesome. Whenever it gets to the main game window, none of the keys seem to work.

Comment: As general recommendation, you would better using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`.  You should also restrict `paintComponent` to painting the current state and should avoid making decisions which might mutate the state, this is what your "main loop" should do.  Swing is not thread safe and you should consider using a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of a `Thread`

Comment: `frame1.setFocusable(false);` isn't going to help you.  The `JButton` is also likely going to steal focus

Comment: *I've tried setting up key bindings,* - see [Motionn Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example to get you started.